# Remove NSWindow content view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I set the content view for the following window and now i want to remove that content view and set it to something else.  I tried just setting the content view to another view and that did not work, how can i just remove it? thanks!

```
    controlFilterBox = [[MoveFilter alloc] initWithFrame:helpWindow.frame];
    [helpWindow setContentView:controlFilterBox];
    [controlFilterBox release];
```

Comment: what do you mean by "that did not work?"

Comment: That it would not respond to changing the content view to another NSView and the view I first use remains there.  I also tried using `[helpWindow setContentView:nil]` and `helpWindow.contentView = nil` which also did not remove the current content view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't remove the contentView (i.e. set it to `nil`). The window requires a view. You probably can get what you're trying to do by calling `[controlFilterBox setNeedsDisplay:YES]`, but I typically recommend that rather than messing with `contentView` itself, you make the views you want to swap to be subviews of `contentView`. Then you can just swap them around as normal views with `removeFromSuperview` and `addSubview:`. It's just often easier than dealing with a special view like `contentView`.